# Can't find php.ini for Wordpress using Hestia

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to locate my php.ini file so that I can increase upload_max_filesize.  Wordpress is installed on an Ubuntu server using Hestia.  I am using Hestia's file manager to look for the file.  As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165558/how-can-i-find-my-php-ini-on-wordpress) thread, I made an asdf.php file to locate php.ini.  It says the location is /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini.  I can't find such a directory even with hestia's search tool.  What am I missing?

Comment: I dont know what Hestia is, but I would guess its a hosting company and therefore YOU cannot access the `php.ini` file that controls possibly 1000 other web sites

Comment: _"What am I missing?"_ - that you might not necessarily have access to a central server folder like `/etc/php/` with your file manager's user, resp. that it might be hidden from you.

Comment: Does this answers your question: [Change php.ini from UI](https://forum.hestiacp.com/t/change-php-ini-from-ui/1290/5)

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `.user.ini` file in the site folders